# Regular Expressions on HTML

Tags: html, regex

I have am using a program that recieves weather information from Yahoo servcies, in this specific case, weather information for Lisbon (Portugal).

- http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=742676&u=c

It is imperative that my program receives a set of numbers. However, I am receiving the content in HTML:

```
<![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/30.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Partly Cloudy, 8 C<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Wed - Sunny. High: 14 Low: 6<br />
Thu - Sunny. High: 12 Low: 8<br />
Fri - AM Showers. High: 14 Low: 6<br />
Sat - Sunny. High: 15 Low: 7<br />
Sun - Sunny. High: 12 Low: 7<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Lisbon__PT/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/POXX0016_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]>
```

Therefore I have the following questions:

1. Is there any regular expression that can help me select only the numbers for `Wed - Sunny. High: 14 Low: 6<br />` temperature?
2. If 1 cannot be done, are regular expressions just not strong enough for this type of work?
   3.If they are not, is there any regular expression that only gives me all the numbers in the file? (The numbers are all I care).

Thanks in advance, Pedro.

Comment: If you use .NET, use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) (or some other html parser). Forget about regular expressions on HTML.

Comment: If you haven't read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/785745), please do. And then get a proper parser.

Comment: The numbers are in the tags right below the description. It's easier to extract them from there with an XML parser.

Comment: Also, you should mention which programming language you're using.

Comment: You can request the API to provide the response in different format by changing the accept header to `application/xml` or something. Tag with a programming language for further help.

Comment: I can't use parsers, that is my big problem. I am literaly forced to use a Regex due to project constraints, that is why I posted this here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups 1 and 2 from this regex contain the two numbers for Wednesday:

```
^Wed.*?High: (\d+) Low: (\d+)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/elPOWD9s9B) of this regex working with your example.